# DTLS handshake failed in ocserv and openconnect

Tags: dtls, openconnect, ocserv

I configured the ocserv on my Ubuntu server with this specefication in `/etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf` file:

```
auth = "plain[passwd=/etc/ocserv/ocpasswd]"
tcp-port = 443
udp-port = 443
run-as-user = nobody
run-as-group = daemon
socket-file = /run/ocserv.socket
server-cert = /etc/ocserv/ssl/server-cert.pem
server-key = /etc/ocserv/ssl/server-key.pem
ca-cert = /etc/ocserv/ssl/ca-cert.pem
isolate-workers = true
#banner = Welcome
max-clients = 128
max-same-clients = 2
server-stats-reset-time = 604800
keepalive = 300
dpd = 60
mobile-dpd = 300
switch-to-tcp-timeout = 25
try-mtu-discovery = false
cert-user-oid = 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1
compression = true
no-compress-limit = 256
tls-priorities = "NORMAL:%SERVER_PRECEDENCE:%COMPAT:-RSA:-VERS-SSL3.0:-ARCFOUR-128"
auth-timeout = 240
idle-timeout = 1200
mobile-idle-timeout = 1800
min-reauth-time = 300
max-ban-score = 80
ban-reset-time = 300
cookie-timeout = 300
deny-roaming = false
rekey-time = 172800
rekey-method = ssl
use-occtl = true
pid-file = /run/ocserv.pid
device = vpns
predictable-ips = true
default-domain = SERVER_IP
ipv4-network = 10.11.12.0
ipv4-netmask = 255.255.255.0
tunnel-all-dns = true
dns = 8.8.8.8
dns = 8.8.4.4
ping-leases = false
cisco-client-compat = true
dtls-legacy = true
```

Then when I want to connect to the server with my Ubuntu machine using OpenConnect, the connection will established but I'm receiving this message:

```
DTLS handshake failed: Resource temporarily unavailable, try again.
Configured as 10.11.12.127, with SSL + LZ4 connected and DTLS + LZ4 in progress
```

And then the first line will repeat every minute.
Is there any solution to fix that? Does my config file has some problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding to this [source](https://www.spinics.net/lists/openconnect/msg03950.html) The problem was in firewall allowed list.
I allowed only PORT/tcp in ufw, then when I allowed the PORT/udp , the problem had been fixed.

```
ufw allow 443/tcp
ufw allow 443/udp
```